# ajax не отправляет форму

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Гуру, подскажите.

Есть форма, при отправке без ajax все ок, ошибок нет, php все принимает.
Ajax ничего не хочет передавать и принимать ответ.

```
$(doc).ready(function () {
    $('body').on("submit", "form",function () {
       // event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            url:  $(this).attr('action'),
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Если закомментировать `event.preventDefault();` и убрать `return false`, все работает.

Comment: смотрите что не так на вкладке `Network` в консоли разработчика браузера. Или же консоли.

Comment: В Network все нормально, код 200, данные с формы верные. Но рнр их не хочет брать и отдавать результат.

Comment: @ВладимирЛебединский а чем (cms/framework ...) данные обрабатываются на стороне сервера?

Comment: Там все просто, в акшене принимается пост запрос, отправляет в базу и в конце json_encode принимает обновленный список продуктов из базы.
Без ajax все передается и возвращается без проблем, а он почему - то не хочет это делать (((

Comment: Не понятно что именно не работает? То, что в консоли пусто, может говорить о том, что никакие результаты не приходят, но сами данные возможно пишутся в БД. После отправки аджаксом в БД есть изменения? А чтобы в консоль приходило, надо их в том вашем акшене формировать...

Comment: И FormData надо формировать ДО $.ajax !!!!! ну азбука же!